# Number parsing behaviour of JS on chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

[image]

can someone tell me why JS or Chrome Browser behaving this way:

if I execute `(Number("09".replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')))/100`
output is `0.09`
But any other division, except 100 the output is undefined

`(Number("09".replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')))/10`

`undefined`

`(Number("09".replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')))/1`

`undefined`

`(Number("09".replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')))/1000`

`undefined`

`(Number("09".replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')))/10000`

`undefined`

`(Number("09".replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')))/100`

`0.09`

this is run on browser JS console of `Chrome Version 83.0.4101.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit)`

Comment: Can't reproduce on 80.0.3987.149. Sounds like a bug

Comment: Also can't reproduce.

Comment: Also working fine on 81.0.4044.92, getting `0.9 9 0.009 0.0009 0.09`

Answer (score 0):

well,  version upgrade fixed the issue. I guess it was just a bad build with some bug. Thanks all for responding.

[image]

current version : `Version 86.0.4221.4 (Official Build) canary (x86_64)`